# ZipArchive for ios - extraction stopped in the middle

Tags: ios, php-ziparchive

I'm using ZipArchive for ios (https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/).

My question is:

If during extraction of a zip file my app is closed (closed on purpose by the user for example), can it potentially happen that **only some** of the files in the zip will be extracted?
Or is it **"all or nothing"**?

Assume the extraction is invoked by:

```
[za UnzipFileTo: outputPath overWrite: YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

after having read the sourcecode I had said that yes, you can have only some of the files extracted, it isn't "all or nothing"

Comment: I checked out the source code as well, and it looks about right. Do you know of some similar library that provides an "all or nothing" zip extraction?